# How can i include an applet in JSF

Tags: jsf, applet

`<jsp plugin>` no works for me? anyway to include applet in JSF ?

Answer (score 2):

Just using object tag:

```
<object width="400" height="300" classid="clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93" archive="applet.jar"
           codebase="http://java.sun.com/products/plugin/autodl/jinstall-1_4-windows-i586.cab#Version=1,4,0,0">
       <param name="code" value="com.mypackage.Main"/>           

       <object width="700" height="500" type="application/x-java-applet" archive="applet.jar">
           <param name="code" value="com.mypackage.Main"/>               
       </object>

   </object>
```

Comment: i tried `<object width="700" height="500" type="application/x-java-applet"  codebase="http://localhost:8070/app/lib/" archive="app.jar">
                <param name="code" value="myapp.NewJApplet"/>        
            </object>` but getting the "myapp.NewJApplet" class not found exception

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like this in JSF. I think you will have to add the required HTML tags to the page yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Html tag will do.. if you going to use applet in many place... you can write a taglip and minimize values to add in your jsp file.

Tablig which gets some values and renders the valuse as  tag.